# Sass not hot reloading in webpack project

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I'm using webpack in my project and currently I'm trying to set up **sass hot reloading**

When I run **webpack-dev-server --inline --hot**, my main.scss, where all other css/scss are imported, is loaded and everything's fine, but as soon as I modify something, it doesn't refresh and I have to restart webpack server

here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: JS_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/client',
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 8080
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      include: JS_DIR,
      loader: 'babel',
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(CLIENT_DIR),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [autoprefixer, precss];
  }
};
```

index.jsx

```
import style from 'css/main.scss';
...
```

main.scss

```
@import './style.scss';
```

style.scss

```
h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Why not to have `loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader']`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the issue

**webpack.config.js** looks like this now:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: JS_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/client',
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 8080
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      include: JS_DIR,
      loader: 'babel',
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(CLIENT_DIR),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

it runs ok with **npm start** (script located in package.json)

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server"
},
...
```

It looks like `'postcss-loader'` was the root of the problem, if I added it to the loaders, it would stop working